# JSForce describeGlobal isn't working when the community has an added URL

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, sobject, jsforce

I have to be able to get all objects on my salesforce community and whenever i utilize the jsforce library to get the connection by using this method "jsforce.Connection"

```
 let conn = new jsforce.Connection({ instanceUrl: null, loginUrl: 
 null, accessToken: sessionId, version:
 apiVersion});
```

later on, i try to obtain every object on that community by using the "describeGlobal" method on the connection i just obtained. This works fine whenever my community has no added URL, however when it does have an added URL, The describeGlobal method doesn't seem to be getting the sObjects and throws a http 503 error. Every bit of help would be much appreciated.

Update: This error occurs whenever ALL my communities have that added URL. For example, if i have 2 communities and let's say the base URL for both communities is "JPBaseURL". If both communities have an added URL, the error above shows, but if just one of them doesn't have that added URL, the error that i mentioned above does not occur. I was not aware that jsforce.Connection method completely ignored the added URL. Any expert on the subject that can help me on this one would be much appreciated.